# Google App Engine Federated Login down? 500 Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine, federated-identity

I am seeing the GAE Error: Server Error page during the federated login request,
appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=...

This is happening with two different applications so it appears to be an issue with GAE.
No code changes or new deployments, it just started happening.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Its back now. Was down for the last 30 minutes.

Comment: Next time you can always check here if anything major is happening.. https://code.google.com/status/appengine